# Product rule for Wirtinger derivatives?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

The Wirtinger derivatives are defined as:

Let $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial  z}= \frac{1}{2}[\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial  y}]$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial  \bar{z}}= \frac{1}{2}[\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial  y}]$$

Now what does the product rule look for these?

Answer (score 3):

As usual, that is 
$$ \partial_z (fg) = \partial_z f \cdot g + f \cdot \partial_z g $$
(the same for $\partial_{\bar z}$). For the proof note that the product rule is true for $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$, we now have
\begin{align*}
  \partial_z (fg) &= \frac 12 \left(\partial_x (fg) - i \partial_y(fg)\right)\\
    &= \frac 12 \left( \partial_x f \cdot g + f \cdot \partial_x g 
    - i  \partial_y f \cdot g -i f \cdot \partial_y g\right)\\
    &= \frac 12 \left(\partial_x f - i \partial_y f\right)g + f \cdot \frac 12 \left(\partial_x g - i \partial_y g\right)\\
    &=  \partial_z f \cdot g + f \cdot \partial_z g
\end{align*}
Along the same line of thought one proves
$$ \partial_{\bar z}= \partial_{\bar z} f \cdot g + f \cdot \partial_{\bar z} g$$

Comment: Yeah I'm confused about the difference of $\partial_z$ and partials $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$. Like they're in a different domain?